# autopep8 does not fix any indentation

Tags: python, autopep8

I have a file `test.py` with the following code

```
class MyClass():
y = 2
def my_func(self):
x = 2
return(x)
```

When I run `pycodestyle test.py` I get

```
test.py:2:1: E112 expected an indented block
test.py:2:1: E305 expected 2 blank lines after class or function definition, found 0
test.py:3:1: E302 expected 2 blank lines, found 0
test.py:4:1: E112 expected an indented block
test.py:4:1: E305 expected 2 blank lines after class or function definition, found 0
```

However running `autopep8 test.py` does not fix any indentation. It returns

```
class MyClass():


y = 2


def my_func(self):


x = 2
return(x)
```

I expect it to return

```
class MyClass():

    y = 2

    def my_func(self):
        x = 2
        return(x)
```

Am I expecting too much of `autopep8`?

Comment: This may be a bug with autopep8. Have you checked their issue tracker on github? https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8/issues